# How to wait for Promise to resolve before returning a new Promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm building a web application for creating retail signage. Firestore holds information about the signs, and I want to be able to remove all of the signs if a user clicks on 'Remove all Signs.' A dialog will then appear which will ask the user to confirm deleting all signs in the database. If they confirm, then all the signs should then be deleted from Firestore.

The document ID of each sign is stored in an array called `signIds`. I want to be able to iterate through `signIds` and delete each document from the `signs` collection in Firestore. Once all the Promises have resolved, I want to return a Promise and resolve it in the event handler in `mounted()`.

I've tried returning a Promise at different places in the code, to no avail. I've also tried using `async` and `await` but that seemed to have the same issue.

```
data() {
        return {
            signIds: [],
        }
},
methods: {
    showModal(message, type) {
        this.$root.$emit('openModal', {
            closed: false,
            text: message,
            type: type
        })
    },
    emptyQueue() {
        let self = this;
        let deleted = 0;

        for (let id of self.signIds) {
            database.collection("signs").doc(id).delete()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
                    deleted++;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
                });
        }

        // Once all signs are deleted, return new Promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return (deleted === self.signIds.length) ? resolve() : reject(new Error('An error occurred while deleting signs.'));
        });
    }      
},
created() {
        // Get and store the document id for each sign
        database.collection("signs").get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    this.signIds.push(doc.id);
                })
            });
    },
mounted() {
        // When the user clicks 'OK' on the dialog, delete all signs from the database
        this.emptyQueue()
            .then(() => {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.showModal('All signs were successfully removed.', 'success');
                }, 300);
            }).catch(() => {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.showModal('An error has occurred. Some signs were not removed.', 'error');
                }, 300);
            })
        }
```

I expect the new Promise to return after Firestore's Promises have resolved, but currently the new Promise is returned immediately after the `for` loop is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current iteration through `signIds`'s `Promises` is not being chained with anything else - the `.delete()` Promises aren't being used anywhere at the moment. It would be better to `.map` each `id` to a `Promise` in an array, then use `Promise.all` on that array. If errors are handled in the consumer, there's no need to `catch` in `emptyQueue` just to throw a new error - instead, just return the Promise chain alone, and avoid the [explicit Promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it):

```
emptyQueue() {
  return Promise.all(
    this.signIds.map(id => (
      database.collection("signs").doc(id).delete()
    ))
  );
}
```

If any one of the `.delete()` calls result in an error, that error will percolate up to your

```
this.emptyQueue()
  // ...
  .catch(() => {
    ...
  });
```

section automatically via the `Promise.all`.

Comment: Great answer, it worked exactly as you wrote it with no errors at all!

Answer (score 1):

Making use of write batch may answer your needs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using `batch`, with a code that should look something like the following:

```
// start a batch
var batch = database.batch();

for (let id of self.signIds) {
  // for each, add a delete operation to the batch
  batch.delete(database.collection("signs").doc(id));
}

// Commit the batch
batch.commit();
```